# How to Codeception and Gitlab CI (Continuous Integration)

Tags: docker, pipeline, gitlab-ci, codeception

I am currently running my acceptance tests via codeception manually. Now its time to do the next step.

I want to create a pipeline in Gitlab to run my acceptance tests automatically.

The very first problem is the .gitlab-ci.yml, where I dont really know how to implement it.

I did it like it was described in this documentation: https://codeception.com/docs/12-ContinuousIntegration

But I am always getting errors.

The newest error is the following:
`*error: zip support requires ZLIB. Use --with-zlib-dir=<DIR> to specify prefix where ZLIB include and library are located*`

I ve tried serveral images from docker hub, but none of them were successful.

This is my current .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
# Select what we should cache
cache:
  paths:
  - vendor/

services:
    - selenium/standalone-chrome:latest

before_script:

# Install git and unzip (composer will need them)
- apt-get update && apt-get install -qqy git unzip

#zip
- apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev
- apt-get update && apt-get install -y libzip-dev
- docker-php-ext-install zip

# Install composer
- curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Install all project dependencies
- composer install

#install node
- apt-get update && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - && apt-get install -y build-essential nodejs
- npm init -y 
- npm install -g eslint --unsafe-perm=true --alow-root
- npm config set prefix ~/.local  
- PATH=~/.local/bin/:$PATH
- apt-get update -q -y
- apt-get --yes install libnss3
- apt-get --yes install libgconf-2-4

#install wget
- apt-get --yes install wget

#install gnupg2
- apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg2


# Install chrome
# Add key
- curl -sS -L https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
# Add repo
- echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
- apt-get update -q -y
- apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable

- npm install chromedriver -g
- npm install https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-selenium-server.git -g
# The `&` at the end causes it to run in the background and not block the following commands

- nohup chromedriver --port=4444 --url-base=wd/hub &
- nohup gitlab-selenium-server &


# Test
test:
  script:
  - vendor/bin/codecept run --env chrome
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried installing zlib1g-dev as well? 
This comment might be helpful - https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/61#issuecomment-468874705 But I suggest by just starting with adding `apt install -y zlib1g-dev` before installing the php extension and see if that solves the issue.

Comment: Another question, how can I use npm install, because if I want to use npm install, it says npm command not found. Can I just add a second image (node) to use it?

Comment: You can simply run `apt-get install -y nodejs` and you should have npm available

Comment: I personally prefer using a shell Gitlab-CI runner with docker and docker-compose installed so I have full control over the actual instance on which I am doing this, but at the same time I can simply use any docker image for composer or npm installs by just mounting my projects in the container and running the necessary commands. It does however sometimes pose issues with permissions so you need to properly configure the instance.
But in your case you should be able to simply install nodejs and run `npm i` just fine

Comment: I used `apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs` but still getting the error: npm command not found

Comment: Can you update the gitlab-ci.yml file with the changes you made?

Comment: I did, hope its not to confusing ^^

Comment: It seems like on stretch npm doesn't come with nodejs... It's always confusing to set it up :D 

You can do this then:

`apt-get update && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - && apt-get install build-essential nodejs`

Tested with the same php image and worked. The curl url depends on which version you want to install.

Comment: That worked for me Buddy thanks a lot, the only thing that is left ist the following error, which happens at: 

`- nohup chromedriver --port=4444 --url-base=wd/hub &
- nohup gitlab-selenium-server &`  

This is the error message I am getting
`nohup: failed to run command 'chromedriver': No such file or directory
nohup: failed to run command 'gitlab-selenium-server': No such file or directory`

Comment: chromedriver is not in your $PATH so it can't be loacted as you installed it locally for your project... You need to either define the full path to it or add the bin folder to $PATH

Comment: I updated my .yml again. I am trying to install chromedriver globally but always get the following error message `Cannot find module '/root/.local/lib/node_modules/chromedriver/install.js`

But when I install it without -g, it installs without a problem